# Getting data from serilized array

Tags: php

I have create a custom meta key into the post table and it's value is in serialized form now when I dump the value it is giving me like this

> Array ( [0] => a:3:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2592";s:7:"user_id";i:41;i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:63:"a:3:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2592";s:7:"user_id";i:2;i:0;a:0:{}}";}} )

I want to get user_id and product_id from it. The main idea is to hide a button for those user whose ID's are stored into this meta_key for the particular product whose ID are in this serialized array as well any idea how to do that I have tried the following code but nothing happens

```
$next_in_line = get_post_meta(esc_attr($product->get_id()), '_next_in_line');
print_r($next_in_line);
$unserilize_data = unserialize($next_in_line);
print_r($unserilize_data['0']);
```

But is giving me bool(false) and when I use this function

```
$next_in_line = get_post_meta(esc_attr($product->get_id()), '_next_in_line');
print_r($next_in_line);
$un_data = maybe_unserialize($next_in_line);
print_r($un_data['0']);
```

it is returning me values in the following format

> a:3:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2592";s:7:"user_id";i:41;i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:63:"a:3:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2592";s:7:"user_id";i:2;i:0;a:0:{}}";}}

Now how can I make the condition that I have mentioned above I am blank at this point please some one help me out. Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I am storing data like this

```
function nextInLine(){
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$next_customer_meta = get_post_meta($product_id, '_next_in_line');

if($next_customer_meta == ''){
    $meta_array = array(
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'user_id' => $user_id
    );

    $meta_value = maybe_serialize($meta_array);
} else {
    $meta_array = array(
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'user_id' => $user_id
    );

    array_push($meta_array, $next_customer_meta);
    $meta_value = maybe_serialize($meta_array);
}
var_dump($meta_value);
update_post_meta($product_id, '_next_in_line', $meta_value);
return true;    

}
 add_action('wp_ajax_nextInLine', 'nextInLine');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nextInLine', 'nextInLine');
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need to unserialize it. update_post_meta and get_post_meta handle that process for you. How are you saving the data?

Comment: Please see I have updated my question and added the code for storing data please see it

Comment: You're serializing the data when you store it. Don't. `update_post_meta` does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$next_in_line = get_post_meta(esc_attr($product->get_id()), '_next_in_line', true);
print_r($next_in_line['user_id']);
print_r($next_in_line['product_id']);
```

Let me know if works.

Comment: The code you give me returns aa that's it no user_id not any product_id

Comment: I am getting 41 & 2592 for user_id and product_id using your array value. Please check your code again

Comment: I have checked it again it is returning me aa please check have i stored the data in the correct way or not I have updated my question

Comment: But it is returning me only one user_id and one product_id but I got two user_id's and two product_id's how to get all the values in array format

Comment: you will have to insert a foreach loop in there somewhere to loop through all users and products.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it the other way by changing my logic what I have done is not a proper workaround but it is working like a charm here's what I have done.

I am now sending only the user_id into the database without serializing.

```
function nextInLine(){
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$next_customer_meta = get_post_meta($product_id, '_next_in_line');
var_dump($next_customer_meta);

if( empty($next_customer_meta) ){
    $meta_value = $user_id;
} else {
    $user_id = $next_customer_meta['0'] . ',' . $user_id;
    $meta_value = $user_id;
}
update_post_meta($product_id, '_next_in_line', $meta_value);
return true;    

 }
  add_action('wp_ajax_nextInLine', 'nextInLine');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nextInLine', 'nextInLine');
```

And then while getting it and writing the condition I used this code.

```
<?php
            if(is_user_logged_in()){
                $next_in_line = get_post_meta(esc_attr($product->get_id()), '_next_in_line', true);
                $status_data = explode(',', $next_in_line);
                if( !in_array(get_current_user_id(), $status_data) ){
        ?>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="next-btn" value="<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>">
                Next 
            </button>
            <span class="text-tiny">
                    Press this button to get in line for this item
            </span>
        <?php
                } else {
                    echo "<h4>You are already in line for this item</h4>";
                } 
            } else { 
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/my-account'; ?>">Login 
            </a><span>to get in line for this item.</span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

The idea was to hide the button if user has already hit it so from this logic I have achieved what I was intended to achieve.

Thank you all for your precious time and effort it really means a lot to me